# edit values in a pandas column- my approach is not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been searching SO for the past couple hours and have tried several times with no joy to do something pretty simple. There is a column in my data frame that looks like this:

```
Name
AEMULUS [S]
AIM
ANCOMLB [S]
APPASIA [S]
ASDION [S]
ASIAPLY [S]
```

I just want to remove the "[S]"

here is the function I wrote to remove the pesky "[S]"

```
def column_fix(df):
"""removes '[s]' from name column"""
    df.Name.str.split()[0]

    return df
```

Comment: I am sure there is a dupe for this but you can use replace df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\[S\]', '')

Comment: You need to assign the splitting back to the Name column

Comment: @ALollz yes, that did the trick.  happy to accept your answer if you add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aproach is almost working. There is no need to wrap it into a function.

Assuming that you are just trying to remove anything after the space, you can just do this:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split(expand=True)[0]
```

Your result:

```
>>> df['Name']
0    AEMULUS
1        AIM
2    ANCOMLB
3    APPASIA
4     ASDION
5    ASIAPLY
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

For a more general aproach, to simply remove all instances of a space followed by a letter in square brackets, use a regex with `replace`:

```
df['Name'].replace(r'\s\[\w\]', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```